# How to run a custom function in typescript if getting it's name as string?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function name as string and i want to run it when page loads first time itself.

here the function

```
StringDateFormat(date:string, format:string) {
    let newDate = new Date(date);
    formatDate = this.datePipe.transform(newDate, format);
    return formatDate
  }
```

i tried by using eval but in angular component's ts file it is not working because it needs the this keyword before function's name.

```
eval("StringDateFormat('2/25/2019','yyyy-mm-dd')").
```

it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it working by some string manipulation and this should work for most of the cases if the string which you receive is consistent.

Try with getting  the funtion name and its arguments and call it like: `this[functionName](...arguments)`

```
  let stringFunc = "StringDateFormat('2/25/2019','yyyy-mm-dd')";
  let func = stringFunc.slice(0, stringFunc.indexOf('('));
  let arg = stringFunc.slice(stringFunc.indexOf('(') + 1, stringFunc.indexOf(')')).split(',');
  this[func](...arg);
```